# Infopath Form - Edit Mode - Error related to list view threshold in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, list-view-threshold

I have an Infopath 2007 Form. 
When I open the edit form(already saved form) , I am getting the below error:

```
The query cannot be run for the following DataObject: MyFormGetInfo InfoPath cannot run the specified query. The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown. The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.0x80070024
```

I dont get this error when I open a new form , make some updates and save it for first time.

Once a form is saved, when I open the Edit Form only then I see this error.
Inspite of this error, I still can make updates to the form and data is saved.

Can anyone suggest how to get rid of this?

Since this is SharePoint Online, we cannot change the listview threshold. Please suggest! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, problem is with you data connection. You need to check your data connection which are used in Infopath Form. There would be one of data connection which would be querying some list without filter, or may be filter would be there in query but the items which are getting returned would be more than threshold value(may be 5000). you need to make sure that any data connections is not querying List which is returning more than 5000 items. Also the columns on which you are filter data should be indexed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a doubt - ultimately, when I open a form in Edit Mode - It will retrieve information matching one single ID only. Right? Its not fetching any items more than 5k.

Comment: Default infopath data connection will retrieve only 1 item based on id, but you might have other data connections which might be fetching items more than 5k..

Comment: I just verified all data connections. There are some dropdowns being filled from different lists which have values less than 100. The data which is being fetched for the form, is retrieved from a list which contains more than 7k items. But the count of whatever items I am retrieving is not exceeding threshold.